# Use of variadic argument ellipsis in a type trait for chrono durations

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, type-traits, c++-chrono

I wrote a type trait template to test whether a type is a `std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>`.  I was stuck for a long time figuring out how to deduce the `Rep` and `Period`.

I patterned this solution on a "[possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class#Possible_implementation)" given for a standard type trait on cppreference.com.  I mostly understand how it works, but I'm confused by the `...` in the signature of the second test function.

- In this case, does that ellipsis indicate a variadic argument list as it does in C?  Or does it take on a special meaning in this context?
- How does the ellipsis help distinguish that test from the other one?  I would have expected SFINAE to be sufficient to figure out which function signature matches.  But if I remove the ellipsis, the compiler reports that they're ambiguous.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

template <typename T, typename Rep = T::rep, typename Period = T::period>
std::bool_constant<std::is_same_v<T, std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>> test();

template <typename>
std::false_type test(...);  // How does `...` help here?

}

template <typename T>
struct is_duration : decltype(detail::test<std::remove_cv<T>::type>()) {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_duration_v = is_duration<T>::value;

static_assert(is_duration_v<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration>);
static_assert(is_duration_v<volatile std::chrono::microseconds>);
static_assert(is_duration_v<const std::chrono::microseconds>);
static_assert(!is_duration_v<double>);
```

---

**ETA 2023-07-29**

My question focused on the variadic argument part of the question, which was answered.  But if you're here for the general type traits context ...

- I voted to undelete Howard Hinnant's answer because it was extremely helpful for me to see a second way to solve the problem, so I believe it would help others as well.
- I ended up defining a concept:

  ```cpp
  template <typename D, typename R=D::rep, typename P=D::period>
  concept Duration = std::is_same_v<D, std::chrono::duration<R, P>>;
  ```

  [Admittedly, that still relies on duration exposing its underlying types, but it makes the approach pretty clear.  (And durations *are* documented to expose those types.)  If you don't relish that, you could use Ted or Howard's example to make a type trait and then define the concept in terms of that.]

  Overloads depending on the concept eliminated the clutter of `enable-if` or `requires`, yielding code that is easy to understand:

  ```cpp
  template <Duration T>
  void Overloaded(T) { std::cout << "Called with a duration.\n"; }

  template <std::floating_point T>
  void Overloaded(T) { std::cout << "Called with a floating point value.\n"; }

  template <typename T>
  void Overloaded(T) { std::cout << "Called with a something else.\n"; }
  ```

Comment: Your code does not seem to compile. You forgot `typename` in several places and the ellipsis pattern actually requires the other `test` function to take an `int` parameter and an argument `0` or something like that at the call site.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Please restore your answer! Its **is** a nicer approach!

Comment: Thanks Ted.  As Adrian has said he tested his code in godbolt, and I am saying it doesn't work, I want to understand this a little better before I put out misinformation.  And actually I wouldn't mind at all if you just added my code to your answer.  It would fit nicely and be less verbose for the reader.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I will gladly wait until you've looked at it a bit closer to wait your your edit (if an edit is even needed).

Comment: MSVC 19 likes it!  [Hey Mikey, it will eat anything!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYEXzx-TINc)  :-).

Comment: FYI: Motivation is an existing generic class that computes statistics (mean, mode, total, etc.) on a population of values.  Most of it works fine with chrono durations, but standard deviation requires temporarily going to an arithmetic type (like double).  I want to hide that detail inside the stats class rather than have the class users throw away the type safety when they provide the timings.

Comment: Oops.  I _was_ testing multiple compilers on godbolt, but I fumbled while iterating.  The code I posted was compiled only with MSVC.  My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does that ellipsis indicate a variadic argument list as it does in C?

Yes.

> How does the ellipsis help distinguish that test from the other one?

It's simply always going to be the "least specialized" of the possible matching overloads, so, if there's another matching overload, that'll be the one chosen.

> if I remove the ellipsis, the compiler reports that they're ambiguous.

Then both matched and you made them equally specialized.

Another way of testing would be to supply an instance of `T` to `test` and see in which `test` it lands. `test(...)` will accept anything and return a `std::false_type` and any class templates taking two template parameters will be using the same condition as in your original. It could look like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct is_duration {
    static std::false_type test(...);

    template <template <class, class> class D, class Rep, class Period>
    static auto test(D<Rep, Period>&) -> std::bool_constant<
        std::is_same_v<D<Rep, Period>, std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>>;

    static constexpr bool value =
        decltype(test(std::declval<std::remove_cvref_t<T>&>()))::value;
};
```

Comment: I like the `template <template <class, class> class D, class Rep, class Period>` suggestion, as that gets away from relying on the duration from exposing its constituent types.  I also love that your solution eliminates the need for extra namespace.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Thanks for those words! I just hope Howard comes back with an edit (if that's needed) of his answer because that approach is in many ways easier to maintain/understand since it just specializes `is_duration` for matches.